# What are the keyboard layouts of a MacBook Pro 15"?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

Can someone find me a picture of Macbook Pro **US keyboard Layout** and one of an **English international**?

I need a detailed image, because I need to know the second key assignments of each key.

Everything I found on Google had too little resolution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find this out yourself.

Open System Preferences-> Language and Text-> Input Sources. Check the boxes for the keyboards you want. Then, check the Show Input menu in menu bar box. Click the new menu bar item, select the keyboard layout you want to see, go back to the menu bar item, and click Show Keyboard Viewer.

This will work from any computer, and you can see any layout.

[image]
[image: (with option key)]

The first picture was snapped while a full sized keyboard was connected, the second shows the option key held down - and is what you will see if you have a smaller bluetooth or built in keyboard connected.

Comment: @bmike thanks for adding the pictures, but you were holding down the option key? I added some normal ones.

Comment: Wow - my MacBook pro only shows the main keyboard - cool seeing the extended picture.  I held the option key down intentionally to show the second key assignments differing between British and U.S. I think the OP has the info needed either way :-)

Comment: @bmike ahh, makes sense. I'll add links to those too.

Comment: show keyboard viewer is not in the menu for me in 2014

Answer (score 0):

US Keyboard layout:
http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/images/MacLaptop-US-shift.png

English International: https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/keyboards/en_international_notebook.png

Comment: that first one isn't for a Mac... But, they are similar.

Comment: Mac = PC in terms of keyboard layout.

Comment: not always exactly, but they're usually pretty close

Comment: You learn something new everyday. :)