# is the keyboard layout for all macbook pro the same?

Tags: keyboard

I have never used a MacBook for professional use and I find myself on a position I might acquire one over the next 6 to 12 months. Though I understand all it's benefits from a technical point of view, I never actually needed one. For all intended purposes, I still don't, as a matter of fact!

My current work laptop is a 3 1/2 year old Dell and I'm running Linux on it and from a professional point of view it suits me just fine.

Right now I live in Brazil and am moving to Europe. So I'd like to know if the keyboard layout is localized (i.e. en_US, en_UK, pt_PT) or it comes only in en_US layout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the keyboard layouts of a MacBook Pro 15"?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17651/what-are-the-keyboard-layouts-of-a-macbook-pro-15)

Comment: @fsb That question on relates to a couple us layouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple provides a list of available keyboards here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794

Which ones are available depends on where you are located.